# beginDialogAction doesn't reprompt

Tags: node.js, dialog, botframework, prompt, chatbot

I am currently using the Microsoft Bot Framework with node.js to write a bot that traverses a decision tree through an API. I want to allow the user to cancel the tree at any point in the dialog, so that he doesn't have to go through the entire (possibly huge) tree to exit. Because i need to send a message to the API if the session is closed, i am using `Dialog.beginDialogAction()` to start a "cancel"-Dialog, instead of `Dialog.cancelAction()`, so that i can prompt the user to confirm as well as close the session.

Now that i have that in place, canceling the tree works just fine, but if the user chooses to say "no" to the confirmation prompt and  the bot should actually re-prompt the last question, it sometimes uses the "no" to answer the previous question automatically (or throws an error). This only appears if the valueType of the question is "string" and a `Prompts.choice` dialog is shown, for `Prompts.number` and `Prompts.time` the expected behaviour is produced.

I have searched any Documentation i could find, but no information about some Prompts not supporting DialogActions or anything like that. I am only using `session.beginDialog`, `session.endDialog`, `session.endConversation` and `builder.Prompts` to control the dialog stack.

Code looks like this:

```
//This dialog gets the next question node of the tree passed in args[1].
bot.dialog('select', [
  function(session, args, next) {
    //Depending on the value type of the question, different prompts are used.
    switch (args[1].valueType) {
      case "string":
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, args[1].text, args[1].answerValues, {
          listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button,
          maxRetries: 0
        });
        break;
      case "number":
        builder.Prompts.number(session, args[1].text, {
          integerOnly: true,
          maxValue: 100,
          minValue: 0
        })
        break;
      case "datetime":
        builder.Prompts.time(session, message + "\nPlease enter a date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.");
        break;
    }
  },
  function(session, results) {
    //Use the answer to proceed the tree.
    //...
    //With the new question node start over.
    session.beginDialog('select', [sessionId, questionNode]);
  }
]).beginDialogAction('cancelSelect', 'cancel', {
  matches: /^stop$/i
});

//This dialog is used for cancelling.
bot.dialog('cancel', [
  function(session, next) {
    builder.Prompts.confirm(session, 'Do you really want to quit?');
  },
  function(session, results) {
    if (results.response) {
      finishSession();
      session.endConversation('Session was closed.')
    } else {
      //Here the bot should stop this cancel-Dialog and reprompt the previous question
      session.endDialog();
    }
  }
])
```

But instead of re-prompting, the bot jumps to `function (session, results)` in the  'select'-Dialog, where it tries to parse the answer "no" and obviously fails.

Here the full copy of my app.js. You wont be able to run it without mocking the esc-API of our product, but it shows that i am only using `session.beginDialog`, `session.endDialog`, `session.endConversation` and `builder.Prompts`. The only changes i did were to remove private information and translate messages to english.

```
/*---------
-- Setup --
---------*/

//esc and esc_auth are product specific, so obviously i cant share them. They handle the API of our product.
const esc = require("./esc");
const esc_auth = require("./esc_auth");
var restify = require("restify");
var builder = require("botbuilder");
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.PORT || process.env.port || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    //Cant share these as well
    appId: "",
    appPassword: ""
});

server.post("/api/messages", connector.listen());

var esc_header;
var esc_session;
var esc_attribs = {};
var treeNames = [];

/*---------
-- Start --
---------*/

//This function is called when no other dialog is currently running.
//It gets the authorization token from the API, reads concepts from the input and searches for matching decision trees.
//If not concepts or trees were found, a text search on the API is cone.
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function(session) {
        var esc_token;
        esc_attribs = {};
        console.log("Getting token...");
        esc.escAccessToken(esc_auth.esc_system, esc_auth.esc_apiUser)
        .then(function(result) {
            esc_token = result;
            esc_header = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + esc_token
            };
            console.log("Got token.");
            //Look for concepts in the message.
            esc.escAnnotateQuery(esc_header, session.message.text)
            .then(function(result) {
                for(i in result.concepts) {
                    for(j in result.concepts[i]) {
                        esc_attribs[i] = j;
                    }
                }
                //If concepts were found, look for trees and solutions with them
                if(Object.keys(esc_attribs).length > 0) {
                    esc.escSearchIndexWithConcepts(esc_header, esc_attribs)
                    .then(function(result) {
                        var treeIds = [];
                        treeNames = [];
                        result = result;
                        result.records.forEach(function(entry) {
                            //Check which tree the found tree is or found solution is in.
                            if(entry.DecisionTree && !treeIds.includes(entry.DecisionTree)) {
                            treeIds.push(entry.DecisionTree);
                            }
                        })
                        if(treeIds.length != 0) {
                            esc.escSearchTrees(esc_header)
                            .then(function(result) {
                                console.log("Trees found.");
                                result.records.forEach(function(tree) {
                                    if(treeIds.includes(tree.DecisionTree)) {
                                        treeNames.push({id:tree.DecisionTree, name: tree.Label})
                                        console.log("Tree: ", tree.DecisionTree, tree.Label);
                                    }
                                })
                                session.beginDialog("tree", treeNames);
                            })
                        } else {
                            console.log("No tree found for " + session.message.text);
                            treeNames = [];
                            session.beginDialog("textSearch");
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("No concepts found.");
                    session.beginDialog("textSearch");
                    return;
                }
            })
        })
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.endConversation("You may now start a new search.");
    }
]);

//Searches for trees by text.
bot.dialog("textSearch", [
    function(session) {
        session.send("No concepts were found in your input.");
        builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Start a text search instead?", {"listStyle": builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    function(session, results) {
        if(results.response) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please enter your new search prompt in keywords.")
        } else {
            session.endDialog("Ok, back to concept search.")
        }
    },
    function(session) {
        //Search gives better results without mutated vowels
        esc.escSearchIndex(esc_header, undoMutation(session.message.text))
        .then(function(result) {
            var treeIds = [];
            treeNames = [];
            result.records.forEach(function(entry) {
                //Check which tree the found document is in.
                if(entry.DecisionTree && !treeIds.includes(entry.DecisionTree)) {
                treeIds.push(entry.DecisionTree);
                }
            })
            if(treeIds.length != 0) {
                esc.escSearchTrees(esc_header)
                .then(function(result) {
                    console.log("Trees found.");
                    result.records.forEach(function(tree) {
                        if(treeIds.includes(tree.DecisionTree)) {
                            treeNames.push({id:tree.DecisionTree, name: tree.Label})
                            console.log("Tree: ", tree.DecisionTree, tree.Label);
                        }
                    })
                    session.beginDialog("tree", treeNames);
                })
            } else {
                console.log("No tree found for " + session.message.text);
                treeNames = [];
                session.endConversation("No trees were found for this search.");
            }
        })
    }
])

//The cancel dialog.
bot.dialog("cancel", [
    function(session) {
        builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Do you really want to cancel?", {"listStyle": builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    function(session, results) {
        if(results.response) {
            if(esc_session) {
                esc.escFinishSession(esc_header, esc_session.sessionId)
                .then(function(result) {
                    esc_session = undefined;
                    session.endConversation("Session was cancelled.")
                })
            } else {
                session.endConversation("Session was cancelled.")
            }
        } else {
            session.endDialog();
        }
    }
])

/*-------------------------
-- Decision tree dialogs --
-------------------------*/

//This dialog presents the found decision trees and lets the user select one.
bot.dialog("tree", [
    function(session, treeArray) {
        var opts = [];
        treeArray.forEach(function(t) {
            opts.push(t.name);
        });
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Following trees were found:", opts, {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button})
    },
    function(session, results) {
        let answer = results.response.entity;
        console.log("Tree selected:", answer);
        let id;
        treeNames.forEach(function(t) {
            if(t.name === answer && !id) {
                id = t.id;
            }
        })
        console.log("Starting session...");
        esc.escStartSession(esc_header, id, esc_attribs)
        .then(function(result) {
            esc_session = result;
            for(i in esc_session.concepts) {
                for(j in esc_session.concepts[i]) {
                    esc_attribs[i] = j;
                }
            }
            console.log("Started session.");
            session.beginDialog(esc_session.questions[0].nodeType,[esc_session.sessionId, esc_session.questions[0]]);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error starting ESC session.");
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
]).beginDialogAction("cancelTree", "cancel", {matches: /^cancel$|^end$|^stop$|^halt/i});

//This dialog is for selection answers on a question node. It also saves recognized concepts within the answer.
bot.dialog("select", [
    function(session, args) {
        console.log("Select");
        message = args[1].text;

        attach(args[1].memo["Memo_URL"]);
        session.userData = args;
        var opts = new Array();
        switch(args[1].valueType) {
            case "string":
                for(var i = 0; i < args[1].answerValues.length; i++) {
                    opts[i] = args[1].answerValues[i].value;
                }
                builder.Prompts.choice(session, message, opts, {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button, maxRetries: 0});
                break;
            case "number":
                for(var i = 0; i < args[1].answerIntervals.length; i++) {
                    opts[i] = args[1].answerIntervals[i].value;
                }
                builder.Prompts.number(session, message, {integerOnly: true, maxValue: 100, minValue: 0});
                break;
            case "datetime":
                for(var i = 0; i < args[1].answerIntervals.length; i++) {
                   opts[i] = args[1].answerIntervals[i].value;
                }
                builder.Prompts.time(session, message + "\nPlease enter a date in format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.");
                break;
        }
    },
    function(session, results) {
        let args = session.userData;
        let answer;
        //An answer was given.
        if(results.response != null && results.response.entity != null) {
            answer = results.response.entity;
        } else if (results.response != null) {
            answer = results.response;
        } else {
            //No answer (to a choice prompt) was given, check if concepts were recognized and try again.
        }
        esc.escAnnotateQuery(esc_header, session.message.text)
        .then(function(result) {
            for(i in result.concepts) {
                for(j in result.concepts[i]) {
                    esc_attribs[i] = j;
                }
            }
            console.log("Proceeding tree with answer %s", answer);
            esc.escProceedTree(esc_header, args[0], args[1].nodeId, args[1].treeId, answer, esc_attribs)
            .then(function(result) {
                if(result.questions[0].nodeType === "error") {
                    //If no concept answers the question, ask again.
                    session.send("No answer was given.")
                    session.beginDialog("select", [esc_session.sessionId, esc_session.questions[0]])
                } else {
                    esc_session = result;
                    console.log("Initiating new Dialog %s", esc_session.questions[0].nodeType);
                    //the nodeType is either "select", "info" or "solution"
                    session.beginDialog(esc_session.questions[0].nodeType, [esc_session.sessionId, esc_session.questions[0]])
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Error proceeding tree.");
                console.log(err);
            });
        })
    }
]).beginDialogAction("cancelSelect", "cancel", {matches: /^abbrechen$|^beenden$|^stop$|^halt/i});

//This dialog is for showing hint nodes. It then automatically proceeds the tree.
bot.dialog("info", [
    function(session, args) {
        console.log("Info");
        message = args[1].text;

        attach(args[1].memo["Memo_URL"]);

        session.send(message);
        console.log("Proceeding tree without answer.");
        esc.escProceedTree(esc_header, args[0], args[1].nodeId, args[1].treeId, "OK", esc_attribs)
        .then(function(result) {
            esc_session = result;
            console.log("Initiating new Dialog %s", esc_session.questions[0].nodeType);
            session.beginDialog(esc_session.questions[0].nodeType, [esc_session.sessionId, esc_session.questions[0]]);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error proceeding tree.");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
])

//This dialog displays the reached solution. It then ends the dialog, erasing the concepts of this session.
bot.dialog("solution", [
    function(session, args) {
        console.log("Solution");
        message = args[1].text;

        attach(args[1].memo["Memo_URL"]);

        session.send(message);
        esc.escFinishSession(esc_header, args[0])
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log("Finished Session " + args[0]);
            esc_session = undefined;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error finishing session.");
            console.log(err);
        })      

        console.log("Ending dialog.");
        session.endDialog("I hope i could help you.");
    }
])


/*-----------
-- Manners --
-----------*/

// Greetings
bot.on("conversationUpdate", function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
        // Don"t greet yourself
        if(message.membersAdded[0].id !== message.address.bot.id) {
            // Say hello
            var reply = new builder.Message()
                .address(message.address)
                .text("Welcome to the Chatbot. Please enter your search.");
            bot.send(reply);
        }

    } else if (message.membersRemoved) {
        // Say goodbye
        var reply = new builder.Message()
            .address(message.address)
            .text("Goodbye.");
        bot.send(reply);
    }
});


/*---------------------
-- Utility functions --
---------------------*/

//function for attached images
var attach = function(p) {
    if(typeof p != undefined && p != null) {
        console.log("Found attachment: %s", p);
        session.send({
            attachments:[{
                contentUrl: p,
                contentType: "image/jpeg"
            }]
        })
    }
}

var undoMutation = function(s) {
    while(s.indexOf("ä") !== -1) {
        s = s.replace("ä", "ae");
    }
    while(s.indexOf("ö") !== -1) {
        s = s.replace("ö", "oe");
    }
    while(s.indexOf("ü") !== -1) {
        s = s.replace("ü", "ue");
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I simplified your code snippet, removed `finishSession();` and the switch condition part, simply 2 waterfull steps with one prompt.number for `select` dialog, and simply `cencel` dialog. But I cannot reproduce your issue, yet. Could you confirm that whether there are any code snippet would effect the dialog stack in the unpost code snippet?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I removed the switch-statement and replaced it with three if-clauses, same result as before. I also checked all the code twice, i am only using session.beginDialog, session.endDialog and builder.Prompts to control the dialog stack, with a few session.endConversation where needed. But i tried out a few combinations and realized, that this error only happens with the Prompts.choice prompt.

Comment: I have also tried to reproduce this error without success.  Please share a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @EricDahlvang Added full app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the question of nested string Prompt dialogs. Currently I only find some workarounds to quick fix the issue.

1. Fastest: Enlarge the retires of prompt dialog, which will reprompt the question if Bot gets the invaild input.

   ```
   builder.Prompts.choice(session, args[1].text, args[1].answerValues, {
         listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button,
         maxRetries: 2
       });
   ```
2. As I see you will pass the `treeNote` to the select dialog, so you can try to use `replaceDialog()` instead of `beginDialog()` to clear nested dialog stack. In your `cancel` dialog, also replace `endDialog()` to `replaceDialog()`

Comment: 1 isn't an option, as i want to allow invalid input, because our system has its own synonym processing and allows for auto-answering questions with recognized concepts, so the user should be able to enter a sentence or multiple answers at any point. But i will try option 2. Thanks.

Comment: Option 2 solved it, replacing the dialog makes it start again and i just have to pass the current node. Thank you!